# Combining Simple products and nominal subscriptions

Tags: recurring

My site at http://www.avantalarm.com/ is trying to sell a simple product (or bundled product) in a security system and we also offer monitoring agreements that require monthly billing and affect the price we offer our customers.  I've added all of our monitoring options as nominal products and included them as an option to add to a security system package.  When I proceed to checkout, it says that I'm unable to go to checkout with a nominal and simple product at the same time.  I'm curious if there is a work around as it is an important aspect to our website.  Any help would be appreciated.  Let me know if I can clarify my question with code as I'm new to StackExchange and new to Magento.

Comment: You may want to check out this discussion here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3202/should-i-use-recurring-profiles-for-subscriptions-feature - the nominal / recurring issue you're hitting is something I hit as well - I decided to build custom.

Answer (score 2):

There currently is no easy way to support checking out with nominal (subscription) items and regular items in the cart at the same time.
It would require reworking big chunks of the sales module, including the totals calculation and order placement.